# Alternative to parameters in a link

Tags: javascript, html, url

I need to store a link with parameters - so that any user can navigate through it and see the corresponding values.

Now it looks like - `www.example.com?param1=1&param2=2`
and simple a tag on UI:

```
<a href="`www.example.com?param1=1&param2=2"> Link </a>
```

Parameters are good at this.

But my customer does not want to see a big link with parameters - is it possible to pass parameters in a hidden way.
I use - `js`

Comment: That's impossible unless you use AJAX to load pages and use short url just for showing purpose.

Comment: The two only ways to give params is POST or GET.. you are using GET. (&param=1&param2=2...) Try using POST method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't use server side tricks, another option is to serialize and encode your parameters in Base 64 or something. You'll still have a parameter, but it'll be one parameter like ?p=f4Q-hi, which is enough to encode quite a bit of data

Answer (score 0):

you can change url by rewrite in htaccess
example:
www.example.com/questions/46077803/alternative-to-parameters-in-a-link
for learn:
https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules
OR
you can save params in coockie